# How to connect to sap bw (on linux server) from azure data factory or synapse analytics pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, sap-bw

There are many posts and documents on connecting to the SAP BW system by installing the self-hosted integration runtime on a windows server. Still, my problem is the sap BW system is running on a Linux environment. Has anyone successfully created a connection from Azure data factory or synapse pipeline to SAP BW running on a Linux environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the steps to connect BW to Azure using the OHD connector.

1. Whitelist the Self-hosted integration runtime IP from
   the BW systems and allow the port 3301(depends on the system number of BW) to connect to the SHIR.
2. Create a technical/service user in sap bw to be used for data loading
3. 64-bit SAP Connector for Microsoft .NET 3.1 need to be installed on
   the SHIR host system.
4. SAP BW Open Hub Destination (OHD) is created with the destination type
   "Database Table"
5. The SAP BW user needs the following permissions:
   Authorization for Remote Function Calls (RFC) and SAP BW.
   Permissions to the “Execute” activity of the S_SDSAUTH authorization object.
6. create the dataset/linked service using the SAP BW Open Hub
   connector with the detail of the OHD from step 3